# XPages HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception Error

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have installed IBM Notes and Domino Designer 9.0.1 locally for testing purposes. Attemping to open any XPage in a database created from the Teamroom template gives HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception. This also occurs with a simple XPage containing just the word TEST and nothing else. Previously I had IBM NOtes 8.5.3 installed and opening XPages worked fine. Could this problem be related to the installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the code is signed by an id with access to run XPages code. Also, install XPages Log File Reader in order to see the detailed error message (which is also available in the XPages log files in the IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT folder on the Domino server)

Comment: Thanks. There is no server in ths case as the installation is local only. I have installed the XPages Log File Reader but of course get the same error when I attempt to open it.

Comment: Not sure what the problem was but I deinstalled and reinstalled Notes and now XPages display correctly